# JQGrid - Setting the expand column width

Tags: jqgrid

I'm deeply customizing the appearance of a jqGrid with subgrid.
One thing I had to do is to change the Expand/Collapse buttons which is supported by the configuration option, no problem.

The thing is that the width of the column where the Expand/Collapse buttons are is the same size of the images and I want to increase its width.

I tried to "hack" the CSS but I couldn't find a nice way of doing it.

So, is there a way to consistently set the Expand/Collapse column width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just place my way of doing it.

```
.jqGridWrapper .ui-sgcollapsed .ui-icon { margin: 8px; }
```

.jqGridWrapper is a class applied to a div that wraps the grid elements.
I use this to make sure my css customizations will only affect what's inside that div.

Cheers!